# UI for Parse error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I would like to add a notification to the user (an AlertView) every time a Parse request is generated and fails. For example, telling the user that the network connection is down or that the username that they have tried is already taken. Is it possible to add UI in one place (like a setting or a subclass) to collect and display all error messages? I would prefer not having to deal with each type of possible error in each `if error != nil` block in every single `PFQuery`.

I understand that some errors are unique and have to be handled individually, but at the same time others are generic, like networking and sign in / sign up, and should have canned user alerts. I know that Parse already does this to some extent, by printing out networking errors, and I was just wondering if there is a way to simply catch these printouts where they are created and alert the user from there. An example of the networking errors that I am talking about is:

```
2015-10-27 22:00:47.501 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:47.501 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.024460 seconds.
2015-10-27 22:00:47.502 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:47.502 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.934890 seconds.
2015-10-27 22:00:47.502 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:47.502 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping for 1.236957 seconds.
2015-10-27 22:00:48.571 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:48.571 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 2.048920 seconds.
2015-10-27 22:00:48.742 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:48.742 YLSA[39956:2216153] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 2.473915 seconds.
2015-10-27 22:00:49.440 YLSA[39956:2216148] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.9.1)
2015-10-27 22:00:49.440 YLSA[39956:2216148] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 3.869780 seconds.
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _add UI in one place to collect and display all error messages_ please be more specific in order to get a specific answer. And the reason why each error is handled in unique blocks is because that reason...they are unique, every situation is different and circumstantially composed. You want to handle errors in their respective blocks because when you come back to your code in a year or so you want to have clean and concise outlines that don't have you going back and forth to files

Answer (score 0):

Most things start and end in a view controller.  Make sure that the methods in your vc that call parse methods have a block parameter that includes the result and an NSError.

Your view controllers may already inherit from a app level vc that centralizes some details about appearance and behavior.  This is a good place to add your generic error handling.

So the app's view controllers:

```
* change the UI to indicate "busy" state
* start a chain of calls that lead to server calls
* results and NSErrors are passed back up the chain 
* in the vc, in the completion blocks:
   - change the UI to indicate not "busy"
   - handle errors for things that are custom to the call
   - call the inherited handler for errors that are handled generically
```